# C# Web Reference работает некорректно

Tags: c#, wsdl

Всем привет. Есть такой сервис https://ws.colissimo.fr/sls-ws/SlsServiceWS/2.0?wsdl
При добавлении его как Web Reference (при добавлении как Service Reference вообще ничего не генериуется) генерируется код, но, как выяснилось с помощью гугла, не тот, который отвечает за получение ответа в формате MTOM. В результате получаю ошибку при выполнении запроса и получении ответа:

***Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; boundary=MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_3CDB24A82E2AD3DD1C1190977590153; type="application/xop+xml";***

Может кто-то указать что не так и как исправить?

Comment: Ну, WSDL не соответствует реальности... бывает. Пишите клиент самостоятельно, Fiddler вам в помощь.

Answer (score -1):

Разработчики дали инструкцию для генерирования References.cs. Там нужно использовать утилиту **svcutil** Спасибо.